# Performing Math.pow and then Updating Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, math

I am building a program which can recieve a group of numbers seperated by a comma and then transfer them to an array and then perform according to a certain Maths method to find the simplest polynomial which can then give us more terms in the sequence. Hopefully that makes sense.

Now i have done the first three steps (with a lot of help from the amazing community here). which are basically this.
1) Repeatedly calculate the differences between adjacent numbers in the sequence, until every number in the sequence is the same:

[1, 1, 5, 13, 25]   ⇒   [0, 4, 8, 12]   ⇒   [4, 4, 4]

2) The exponent of the new term is the number of steps above, i.e. 2.

3) The coefficient of the new term is the number on the final sequence divided by the factorial of the exponent, i.e. 4/2! = 2. Thus the new term is 2x^2.

Now the fourth step is a little weird.

Subtract the new term from each element of the original sequence. From the first element subtract 2 * 1^2, from the second subtract 2 * 2^2, from the third subtract 2 * 3^2, etc. This leaves [-1, -7, -13, -19, -25], which is the sequence of numbers to start the next iteration.

I had a look and Math.pow is a method that i might be able to use but i am unsure how to actually do that. I right now have a method implementing the first three steps which is the following.

```
public Term nextTerm(){
   double[] lastSequence = sequence;
   int steps = 0;
   while ( !allEqual(lastSequence)) {
      lastSequence = differences(lastSequence);
      steps++;
   }
        return new Term(lastSequence[1]/factorial(steps), steps); 
   }
```

and the newTerm i believe should give me the coefficent and exponent.

I was looking it over. I think i have a idea.
i could use a for loop under that method so it looks like this.

```
for(i=0;i<=sequence.length;i++){
sequence[i] - Term.getcoefficient * Math.pow(i,Term.getExponent)
}
```

please let me know if this and how will i then update the sequence array.

Can anyone please help me here. Thanks guys.

Comment: If someone could please tell me if the above solution that i came up with is somewhat close or i am going in the right direction? I would very much appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm following, but you may find it easier to work with Newton's Interpolation Polynomial. Instead of adding a new term 2x^2, you would add a new term 2x(x-1). Then you don't have to mess with the other terms (subtracting, etc.). In the end you'll get a polynomial which looks like `c_0/0! + c_1/1! x + c_2/2! x(x-1) + c_3/3! x(x-1)(x-2) + ...`. You can simplify that polynomial later if you wish, or not.

Comment: Yes Edward, I understand that but this is actually for a university project and they decided to use this way for some reason. There are many things that could be made simple in the program but they are sorta forcing us to do it their way. So yeah. Unfortunately not that great. Do you have any idea if i am right with the for loop i came up with? Its giving me a compiler error: not a statement so i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: The for loop looks almost correct. The only problem I see is that the first - should be -=. Otherwise it works as you describe.

Comment: Hmm. No i am trying to take away the term which is came up with using Term.getcoefficient * Math.pow(i,Term.getExponent and then take that away from every term of the sequence. So it should be right but then i also want to replace that into the sequence afterwards. So basically. For example. If i have sequence[1] = 1 then i want to do is 1 - 2(1)^2 and then replace the resulting value in sequence[1]. i don't know how to do the replacement etc. can you help there?

Comment: What i just thought of and did is this.
i used sequence[i] = the statement above and thats now good. but now i have error that cant find Term.getCoefficient. This is actualy a method in another class called Term which just returns coefficient. Why is this? Please help if you can.

Comment: sequence[i] = sequence[i] -  Term.getcoefficient * Math.pow(i,Term.getExponent);

Comment: Hi. I did that. but that doesn't actually work. It gives me a error saying cant find getCoefficient. I dont know how to solve that.

Comment: You haven't included definition for the Term class. It should have methods to retrieve information, namely getCoefficient() and getExponent(). Then your for loop can be `sequence[i] = sequence[i] - Term.getCoefficient() * Math.pow(i,Term.getExponent());`

Comment: yes. Sorry. i figured it out. It was a very stupid typo just messing it up. I really really appreciate your help. I had both those methods that just returned the variables but i was doing Term.getCoefficient and not Term.getCoefficient() .. I can't believe how someone makes such stupid mistakes. But thankyou again.